# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "doler prendas"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Leo en un artículo:

> Toca ahora estigmatizar cualquier protesta contra la turistificación o la masificación de un turismo insostenible que daña ya en muchos casos los intereses de los habitantes del territorio. Y es que **no les duelen prendas** a la hora de pregonar que cualquier cosa que dé dinero ha de ser reverenciada sin cuestionamiento ninguno.
>
> <sub>[*Del café al porro*](https://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/cafe-porro_6_672692731.html), Elisa Beni en eldiario.es, 5 agosto 2017</sub>

Como se ve, se utiliza esta expresión para decir *esta gente no duda en defender algo a toda costa*.

El DLE recoge:

> [**no dolerle a alguien prendas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U2AR2kw)
>
> 1. loc. verb. Ser fiel cumplidor de sus obligaciones.
> 2. loc. verb. No escatimar garantías, concesiones, gastos o recursos para lograr un acuerdo u otro propósito cualquiera.

Pero no deja de sorprenderme la expresión, pues ¿qué pintan las prendas [de ropa] en un tema así?

Hay quien apunta:

> La expresión, que probablemente se gestó en el ámbito jurídico, guarda estrecha relación con el proverbio ‘a buen pagador no le duelen prendas’, que ya aparece en El Quijote.
>
> <sub>[«No me duelen prendas»](https://fraseomania.blogspot.com/2018/04/no-me-duelen-prendas.html)</sub>

El origen jurídico podría tener su sentido, máxime cuando su uso es escaso y la periodista de quien lo leí (Elisa Beni) está especializada en temas jurídicos. Pero el blog no da más detalles.

Tampoco veo ninguna referencia contrastable en el artículo [*¿De dónde surge la expresión ‘no doler prendas’?*](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-no-doler-prendas/) de *Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe*.

> El acto de pagar o realizar algún tipo de trabajo con el fin de recuperar ese objeto dejado como prenda fue lo que originó la expresión ‘no doler prendas’ (o en la forma ‘no doler prendas a alguien‘) y  aunque hoy en día está cada vez está más en desuso, todavía se utiliza  para referirse a aquel que satisface un pago y cumple con su deber sin importarle el esfuerzo que hace por ello.

Así pues, ¿cuál es su origen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues el origen queda claro si tomas la palabra *prenda* de forma literal... pero literal tal y como se entendía en el siglo XVI.

Efectivamente, la expresión original fue "al buen pagador no le duelen prendas", como se atestigua en textos ya en el citado siglo:

> *Señora, que assí está bien, que al buen pagador no le duelen prendas; ves aquí cuatro ducados para una saya, para paga y señal.*
>
> Feliciano de Silva, "Segunda Celestina", 1534 (España).

¿Nunca has dado algo *en prenda* a cambio de otra cosa? Efectivamente, si consultamos el *Diccionario de Autoridades* encontramos lo siguiente:

> PRENDA. La alhája que se dá ò entrega para la seguridad de alguna deuda ù contrato.

Y de aquí también tienes *prendar*:

> PRENDAR. Sacar alguna alhája ò prenda para la seguridad de una deuda, ò para la satistaccion de algun daño cometido.

Es decir, que por ejemplo tú podías recibir un préstamo y tú dabas a cambio una joya *en prenda* que el prestamista podía quedarse si no lo devolvías. Esto me suena... sí, básicamente lo que hoy día se hace en una casa de empeños.

Por tanto, si eres buen pagador no sentirás el dolor de perder ninguna prenda querida, como joyas de la familia o cualquier otra cosa de valor por la que puedas sentir apego. Esto explica la primera acepción actual de la expresión: ser fiel cumplidor de tus obligaciones. La segunda supongo que surgió como consecuencia: a veces se podía dar en prenda cualquier cosa con tal de cumplir un objetivo. Este sentido al principio sería literal, pasando a ser figurado posteriormente.

Y ahora nos quedamos con una duda. El *Diccionario de Autoridades* no recoge ninguna acepción de *prenda* en el sentido de ropa. ¿Cuándo adquirió la palabra esta acepción, añadida al diccionario de la RAE en 1869<sup>1</sup>? ¿Será porque muchas veces se dejaban prendas de ropa como *prenda* de los préstamos o daños ocasionados?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Otros diccionarios la recogen antes, como el Salvá de 1846.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre lo he vinculado con este significado: PRENDA.

La alhaja que se dá o entrega para la seguridad de alguna deuda u contrato.

Comment: Interesante, manuteris. Sería interesante que aportaras alguna fuente que respalde esta hipótesis, ¿tienes alguna a mano? :) Y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]